# JAVA SE fundamental

Tags: java

How does the `compareTo()` method actually work?
I even looked at the API Documentation but I am still not getting it.
Also, what if the song passed to the method is an `ArrayList` of `Song` objects?

```
class Song implements Comparable<Song> {
    String title;
    String artist;
    String rating;
    String bpm;

    public int compareTo(Song s) {
        return title.compareTo(s.getTitle());
    }

    Song(String t, String a, String r, String b) {
        title = t;
        artist = a;
        rating = r;
        bpm = b;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }
    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }
    public String getBpm() {
        return bpm;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format the code properly. BTW what is that you are really asking? The code you have posted has implemented the `compareTo` method. It says that comparing two `Song` is equals to comparing their titles.

Comment: "Also What if the Song passed to the method is ArrayList of song object?" That would never happen, the compiler would disallow it.

Comment: Sir, sorry for the anomalies . Tried as novice here.

Answer (score 0):

## About Interfaces

`Comparable` is an [*interface*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html). If a class `implements` an interface, the class is **required** to implement a **definition** ("implementation") of the methods that have been **declared** in the interface. The method **implementation** needs to have a matching *[method signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)*.

The `Comparable<Song>` interface has declared one method, `int compareTo(Song)`. This is the *method signature*.

In your code, you therefore have to **implement** a method using the **same signature**. This is exactly what you have done, as far as I can tell. :)

Your implementation simply calls the `compareTo()` method of a `String` (strings implement `Comparable<String>`, which is why this works). The `String` implementation of `Comparable<String>` simply compares two strings lexicographically, as suggested in the [Official Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

---

## Why Use Interfaces?

Interfaces are a great way to predefine behavior in classes. For instance, the `List` interface in Java contains predefined behaviors of a list. This interface has a lot of different implementations, which have better performance in specific scenarios (e.g ArrayList, LinkedList).

Hope this helped :)